# When compiling I get an error, `@LIBICONV@: No such file or directory`?

Tags: compiling

When I run `make` for [flac](http://xiph.org/flac/), I get this

```
gcc: error: @LIBICONV@: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [flac] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/flac/src/flac'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/flac/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/flac'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

While `aclocal.sh` ran successfully (exit code 0), I got this when I ran it,

```
configure.ac:308: warning: macro `AM_ICONV' not found in library
configure.ac:309: warning: macro `AM_LANGINFO_CODESET' not found in library
configure.ac:308: warning: macro `AM_ICONV' not found in library
configure.ac:309: warning: macro `AM_LANGINFO_CODESET' not found in library
```

I tried looking for an `inconv.h`, or for an `iconv-dev` package with my distro and I couldn't find one. How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [bug is documented here](https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/8422). However, none of the suggested fixes worked for me. It's not a header file you need, it's a macrofile: namely `iconv.m4`

If you use Ubuntu can you see here what provides these files,

```
$ apt-file search iconv.m4
gettext: /usr/share/aclocal/iconv.m4
gnulib: /usr/share/gnulib/m4/iconv.m4
```

The .m4 that worked for me was in **`gettext`**. That's the only one I tried -- because there was other obvious indicators that `aclocal` was being used in the build process. Simply run,

```
$ sudo apt-get install gettext
```